# Trigger click on lower element (z-index)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [click link below a higher z-index div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740242/click-link-below-a-higher-z-index-div)

I have a small question. I have a few div elements in my code.
They represent a kind of building. Now you have a front element (porch) and a back element (building).
In the back element there will be a movie, but because the front element (porch) has a higher z-index the button will not work.

A solution could be that a set the movie z-index higher (or move the element to the front), but because there is an element moving between the front and back (the element must move in front of the movie) i can not do this.

I wondered if there is any solution that you can trigger clicks from element that have a lower  z-index or are lower in the structure. I heard there was a jquery plugin to do this, but I can not find it.

Thanks

```
<div id="cases" class="chapter">
    <div class="building sprite"></div>
    <div class="porch sprite"></div>
    <div class="movie">
        <iframe width="695" height="435" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/O9REMmhvjQw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this link:

[Forwarding mouse events through layers](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/)

It deals with passing mouse events from one element to another using a littlwe known property of Javascript.

Another solution is also [available here](http://jsbin.com/uhuto).