# detect mouseover/mouseclick regardless of z-order / layer level

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a way to detect mouse events (hover, click, ...) on elements that are behind other HTML elements but *not within the same DOM path* (i.e. events do not bubble up to the element)?

A quick example to clarify what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/xeJyg/1/

At the moment I don't see other option except for registering the event handler on the first common parent (in the example above that would be `<BODY>`) and check myself if the event happened above the element in question. The problem is that with many elements this will probably become very inefficient.

In the long turn I try to catch mouse events for markers on multiple OpenLayer layers, which is not supported out of the box (events work only for the top layer).

Comment: I think that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737480/passing-mouse-clicks-through-an-overlaying-element-div may give you a start.

Comment: Thanks, but that comes close to my mentioned inefficient do-it-yourself method and I dont really like to hide/show a number of layers containing a few hundred markers on mousemove... :-/

Answer (score 3):

on newer browser you can use `pointer-events: none;`

```
#cover {
    ...
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PVxbq/

Comment: That would still only allow me to receive events on a single layer. However, I have several layers with markers and I need to catch events for all layers/events.

Comment: Actually that was indeed an important hint. It turned out that only the OpenLayers *Vector* layers blocked mouse events and setting `pointer-events:none` for those layers solves the problem (since I only need mouse events on Markers, not Vectors). +1 for solving my main problem. I let the original question open since it is still not solved.

Comment: Shoulda guessed it wouldn't work on IE9 when you said "newer browser"; Boo for IE :(

Comment: @widgisoft , probably "modern" would have been a better adjective: http://caniuse.com/pointer-events